# regex adding linebreaks at every dot in a text except for defined abbreviations

Tags: regex, bash, macos, shell, sed

I am trying to find a regex for a bash shell script in Mac OS-X which replaces dots (.) into linebreaks (\n) in a big text file. 
But dots used for common abbreviations like tel. etc. Mr. Ms. U.S. and some others should be excluded.

So far I am using sed for simple replacements already (but of course the ignore-part is missng):

```
LC_ALL=C sed -i "" -e "s/.*SEARCH.*/REPLACEMENT/" ascii.txt
```

**example:**

```
Mr. Brown searches his fox. My tel. nr. can be found online. U.S. is a typical abbreviation for the United States.
```

**the result should be:**

```
Mr. Brown searches his fox.\n 
My tel. nr. can be found online.\n
U.S. is a typical abbreviation for the United States.\n
```

Comment: This will be nearly impossible with regular expressions alone - where is the difference between `Mr.`, `tel.`, `nr.` and `online.` (where it should match). You could try to fiddle around with the length but this is very error-prone. The bottom line: what makes a sentence a sentence (characterwise, that is) ?

Comment: Do you have a file with all abbreviatons to be skipped?

Comment: I found some solutions with a negative look-ahead - which almost fullfill my needs:

^/(?!ignoreme|ignoreme2|ignoremeN)([a-z0-9]+)$

Comment: I only have <10 abbreviations which have to be ignored. The result of the script will be over-worked by human anyway but it could safe a lot of work if it 'filters' the majority of real sentences before.

Comment: OP, does the answer *have* to use bash? I don't think shell scripting is the ideal way to handle this; I think you'd be better suited writing a quick Python script to handle it or something. I can write a complete example for you if you think that's acceptable.

Comment: this is part of an already existing bash script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After final testing I found out an even worse problem: sed is interpreting "\n" as text so I tried a different approach with "tr" which brings other problems for me.

Finally I ended up again with sed and the following works for me on Mac OS-X 10.11.3:

```
sed -E $'s/\./\.\\\n/g; s/(ca|Ca|Mr|Ms|etc|[0-9])\\n/\\1./g;' test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use GNU `sed` like this:

```
sed -r 's/\./\n/g; s/(Mr|tel|nr|U|S)\n/\1./g; s/\n */\n/g'
```

If your `sed` implementation does not support extended regular expressions, you need to say something like

```
sed 's/\./\n/g; s/\(Mr\|tel\|nr\|U\|S\)\n/\1./g; s/\n */\n/g'
```

If your `sed` implementation does not support that either, then you need to handle all abbreviations separately, e.g.

```
s/Mr\n/Mr./g; s/tel\n/tel./g;
```

and so on. If your `sed` implementation can handle **that, either**, then it's time to look for another operating system.

Comment: sed -r is an illegal option for the standard sed used by OSX.

Comment: sed 's/\./\n/g; s/ replaces every "." into a "n" ignoring the excludes at all. OSX is using the BSD sed which seems to be limited. maybe regex or awk might be an approach ..?

Comment: After escaping the backslash before \n with another backslash \\n it works on OSX:
LC_ALL=C sed 's/\./\\n/g; s/ca\\n/ca./g; s/Ca\\n/Ca./g; s/0\\n/0./g; s/5\\n/5./g;' test.txt
But of course the result is NOT a regexp with exclusions but something like "backward - forward". 
First step: all "." are converted, then second step: reconvert the unwanted changes.